# CropperJS cropper Destroy Issue fengyuanchen/cropperjs

Tags: javascript, crop, cropperjs

I am trying to destroy cropper when model close here is my code
i am using https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

```
var image = document.getElementById('image_cropper'); 
var cropper = new Cropper(image); 
cropper.destroy(); 
cropper = null;
var cropper = new Cropper(image , options); // options are defined on top
```

I select one image and close model after select new one
and here is the result
[image]

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: I was able to do it `$('#croppermain').html('');` `$('#croppermain').append(el);` `cropper.constructor(el);` where el is image element after setting new src, i understand its not an ideal way let me know if there is better workaround